# Coloring rooms of house obeying given rule

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, inclusion-exclusion

> The rooms in the circular house plan shown below are to be painted using eight
> colors such that rooms with a common doorway must be different colors. In
> how many ways can this be done?

[Click here to see related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXClz.png)

The foregiong question is solved by exclusion-inclusion.The given answer is $$8^4-\binom{6}{1}8^3 +\binom{6}{2}8^2-\bigg[\bigg(\binom{6}{3}-2\bigg)8 +2 \times8^2\bigg]+\bigg[\binom{6}{4}-\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{6}\bigg]8$$

I agree with given answer except for the part $$\bigg[\bigg(\binom{6}{3}-2\bigg)8 +2 \times8^2\bigg]$$

because I think that there are more than $2$ selections which will cause $8^2$

[Here my marked picture for my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMqzd.png)

I think that selection of $(e2,e4,e6),(e1,e2,e3),(e3,e4,e5),(e1,e5,e6)$ cause $8^2$, so the answer should have been $$8^4-\binom{6}{1}8^3 +\binom{6}{2}8^2-\bigg[\bigg(\binom{6}{3}-4\bigg)8 +4 \times8^2\bigg]+\bigg[\binom{6}{4}-\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{6}\bigg]8$$

Am I right or missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

Each two rooms have a common door. Therefore each two rooms have  different colors. Therefore $4$ distinct colors are used for the rooms. The ways to color $4$ rooms distinctly using $8$ colors are $\binom{8}{4}*4! = 1680$ which matches your answer. Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Sometimes I think we could teach an entire course on "how to spot what is essential to a problem and discard the obfuscations".